# Laravel-React changes does not work even with npm run dev

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel, installation

This is my first time installing laravel and plan to use react with it through this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=svziC8BblM0). The problem is the changes does not work like what was shown in 19:06 in the video. I used the id from the php file `app` to use it in the jsx file like what was shown in the video.

In my example.jsx file

```
if (document.getElementById('app')) {
    ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById('app'));
}
```

In the app.blade.php file

```
    <div id="app">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-white shadow-sm">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url('/') }}">
                    {{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}
                </a>
```

I also cant use npm run watch because NPM err! no module watch even if i npm install already.

Comment: Laravel now uses vite which does not include a `watch` command which means the tutorial you have found is out of date. The docs for the laravel vite integration are [here](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/vite)

Comment: @apokryfos well i be dammed. Do you have any good suggestions for tutorials? I really wanted to learn laravel with react. Appreciate it

Comment: I don't know any good tutorials for this (and since this was a relatively recent move it may be a while until decent ones come out). I think for now you need to be going through the docs I linked above and also the [laravel-vite docs](https://laravel-vite.dev/) and there's also discussions in Laracasts such as [this](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/vue/how-to-use-laravel-vite). Roughly speaking you would be replacing any blade `@mix` directives with the equivalent `@vite` ones and running `npm run dev` to run the vite development server

Answer (score 0):

I have one solution. In package.json add a new vite line adding on --watch.

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "watch": "vite build --watch"
},
```

we can then run npm run watch and have the same automatically built production resources.

If you want hot reloading as well, open a second terminal window and run npm run dev. When code changes then both scripts run, creating production assets and hot reloading.

The couple also with Freek's tip about hot reloading on blade updates

[tutorial link](https://freek.dev/2277-using-laravel-vite-to-automatically-refresh-your-browser-when-changing-a-blade-file)